# Javamail How to stop or cancel sending or retrieving message

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I have tried `Transport.close()` or `Store.close()`. But it didn't stop or cancel the process sending or retrieving emails using `Javamail` in Android.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to put the `sendMail()` method in its own thread and kill/close this one to prevent it from beeing executed.

Hope this helpes, have Fun!